# Viewpager: problems with left-to-right swipe

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe-gesture

I have a ViewPager inside LinearLayout. It works correct when I swipe to the next fragment (from right to left), I can touch screen on any place and it works. But when I try to back to previous fragment, swipping from left to right, it works only on a narrow part on the left side of screen (yellow area on picture):

[image]

My xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/palette_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        tools:context="com.internet_of_everything.chineesecards.MainActivity">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:contentDescription="@android:string/untitled"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_back" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:contentDescription="@android:string/untitled"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/button_next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**
In my fragment I have 2 linear layouts: with EditText and with TextView. On the same time only EditText or TextView can be shown.
And I have onTouchListener: when EditText is shown it hides keyboard and checks the content of EditText when user clicks outside this edittext. 
So am I able to use this onTouchListener and solve problem with left-to-right swipe?

```
public class OneCardFragment extends Fragment {

    public OneCardFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                //hides keyboard
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(rootView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                //checks edittext content
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think its not a ViewPager problem directly. Check your second fragment's layout and click listeners, may be some views consume the touch event before, and prevent swipe gestures.

Comment: You are right, I have onTouchListener in my Fragment. I updated my question with some details about it

Comment: Are you returning `true` inside of the method `boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`? If yes return `false` that the other view can have a chance to handle the event too.

Comment: It works, thank you!! I dont know how can I mark your comment as an answer

Comment: I will add an answer, so you can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return false that the other view can have a chance to handle the event too.

```
public class OneCardFragment extends Fragment {

    public OneCardFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                //hides keyboard
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(rootView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                //checks edittext content
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```